# Entity Framework Query based on child object filter and at the same time on the main object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a class called Query with a field called CreatedBy, the username who created it.
I also have a class called Permissions with the permissions for the query.

I created a query that returns me based on the current user, the queries the user has access to, based on the Permissions collection, but I need to JOIN that with the queries that the user also created.

If for some reason, the user who created it, its also in the Permissions collection, it shouldnt be returned twice.

Here is my code

```
public class Query
    {
        public int QueryId { get; set; }
        public string QueryName { get; set; }
        public string QuerySql { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string QueryType { get; set; }
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Operator1 { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Connector2 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Operator2 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
        public string Connector3 { get; set; }
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Operator3 { get; set; }
        public string Value3 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Permission>  Permissions { get; set; }
    }


  public class Permission
    {
        public int PermissionId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

   public IQueryable<Query> GetQueriesForUser(string userName)
        {
            return _context.Queries.Where(q => q.Permissions.Any(p => p.UserName.Equals(userName)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need a join? It looks like you need `UNION ALL`:

```
_context.Queries.Where(q => q.Permissions.Any(p => p.UserName == userName)).Concat(
    _context.Queries.Where(q => q.CreatedBy == userName));
```